# asp.net mvc onr-to-many details partial view in master main view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, one-to-many, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I am sorry if im asking same thing for the nth time but i can not find the answer to my question...

I have problem adding partial views...

I have One-to-Many relation in the database tables.

My Model is:

```
 using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public partial class Job
{
    public Job()
    {
        this.Flights = new HashSet<Flight>();
    }

    public int JobID { get; set; }
    public string JobNumber { get; set; }
    public int ClientID { get; set; }

    public virtual Client Client { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Flight> Flights { get; set; }
}
```

My Controller (Create):

```
  // GET: /Jobs/Create
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        ViewBag.ClientID = new SelectList(db.Clients, "ClientID", "ClientName");
        return View();
    }
```

And View (for create Job):

```
@model AOG.Models.Job

<div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>Job</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.JobNumber, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.JobNumber)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.JobNumber)
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ClientID, "ClientID", new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownList("ClientID", String.Empty)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ClientID)
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now if i add partial view (Generated Partial List View) On Create Job Page:

```
@html.Partial("_PartialFlights");
```

I get an error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object on

```
Line 23: @foreach (var item in Model) {
```

in my partial view. This is the code:

```
@model IEnumerable<AOG.Models.Flight>
<table class="table">
<tr>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FlightName)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FlightETD)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FlightETA)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Job.JobNumber)
    </th>
    <th></th>
</tr>
@foreach (var item in Model) {
<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FlightName)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FlightETD)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FlightETA)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Job.JobNumber)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.FlightID }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.FlightID }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.FlightID })
    </td>
</tr>}</table>
```

How ever If i put this in the details view:

```
    @foreach (var item in Model.Flights)
{
    <div>
        <table>
        <tr><th>Flight</th><th>ETD</th><th>ETA</th></tr>
        <tr>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FlightName)</td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FlightETD)</td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FlightETA)</td>
            </tr></table>    

 </div>
}
```

It shows everything I need, but i want to learn how to do it with the partial views.

Thank you all so much!

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass an `IENumerable<Flight>` instance to your partial view, so in stead of:

```
@html.Partial("_PartialFlights");
```

...do this:

```
@html.Partial("_PartialFlights", Model.Flights);
```